# Is it possible to reset ':invalid' CSS pseudo-class on required input field on firefox?

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have a form submitted with Ajax.
After data is sent, I simply empty all the fields, however I notice on firefox, a red box-shadow which stays on **required** fields.

Here is an example of the issue:

```css
input:invalid {
}

input:valid {
}


body {
  padding: 3em;
}
fieldset {
 border: 0;   
}
input {
  padding: 0.25em 0;
  margin-bottom: 0.75em;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <label for="email">Reset when empty:</label>
  <input type="email" name="email">
</fieldset>
  
<fieldset>
  <label for="emailRequired">Not reset when empty (required):</label>
  <input type="email" name="emailRequired" required>
</fieldset>
```

I can correct the issue with (but create other issues):

```
input:invalid {
    box-shadow:none;
}
```

Is it possible to reset the normal behaviour without adding styling?

Comment: Use javascript to remove the `required` attribute or otherwise adjust the criteria that the red border is shown? Such as Javascript adding a `.sent` (*for example*) class which cancels the `:invalid` pseudo-selector.

Comment: once form was sucessfully sent, there should be a message that tells clearly that it was sucessfully sent., then the empty fields won't matter, else, refill the fields with the value sent and still with the CLeAR message that form/request was sucessfully submitted. Make it clear for the user , do not relay on style that can be misunderstood ;)